# RESTful - get list of resources by owner ID

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I need to get list of departments who belong to a specific division. The `/dept/1` URL, according to the REST basics, should be used for getting a specific department by ID, so it can't be used here.

Then I have the following options:

`/dept/division/1`

Doesnt look as true REST. Also, I don't know how to implement it in WebApi actions terms.

`/dept?divId=1`

Looks more RESTful. It will require the `Get(int divId)` action created, but there's also `Get(int id)` one that is for retrieving a single department and has same signature.

`/dept (with divId=1 in the body)`
Is it RESTful enough? It'll have same signature problem like in #2 though...

Please advice which way is better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DivisionsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("/Divisions/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Division GetDivision(int id)
    {
        return // your code here
    }

    [Route("/Divisions/{id}/Dept")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Department> GetDepartments(int id)
    {
        return // your code here
    }

    [Route("/Divisions/{id}/Dept/{deptId}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Department GetDepartment(int id, int deptId)
    {
        return // your code here
    }
}
```

Or in a more succinct way

```
[RoutePrefix("/divisions/{id}")]
public class DivisionsController : ApiController
{
    [Route]
    [HttpGet]
    public Division GetDivision(int id)
    {
        return // your code here
    }

    [Route("Dept")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Department> GetDepartments(int id)
    {
        return // your code here
    }

    [Route("Dept/{deptId}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Department GetDepartment(int id, int deptId)
    {
        return // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, visual studio doesn't spell check :)

Comment: Actually you don't have to do the string.Empty thing. Updating

Answer (score 3):

How I would do it

```
/divisions/1/depts
```

`/divisions/1` gets the single division with ID 1, and the `/depts` behind that gets all departments that belong to that specific division

This could then of course be extended to

```
/divisions/1/depts/234
```

To get department with ID 234, of division 1.

There's no need to pass information through a body this way.

I used plurals for the resource names because I'm used to doing it like that, if you want to use `division` and `dept` instead that would be just fine.

Comment: yes, it's a good 4th option. Please, how your Division controller action would look like?

Comment: And it's very RESTful unlike most night of sleep for me!

Comment: @LINQ2Vodka I'm responding to the REST part of the question, I'm not familiar with asp.net so I can't help you there :-(

Comment: @TimCastelijns, thank you anyway. I'll wait for .net answers. Voting up.